# If $n>1$ is odd, show that $n$ divides an element of $\{2^1-1, 2^2-1, \cdots , 2^{n-1}-1\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the numbers: $\{2^1-1, 2^2-1, \cdots , 2^{n-1}-1\}$
Let $n$ be an odd number $> 1$.
Show that it's not possible for each of the numbers in the above set to leave a different remainder among $\{1,2,3,....,n-1\}$

Now my solution goes as follows:
$\phi(n)<n$ and so $n\mid 2^{\phi(n)}-1$, thus contradicting the statement.

But I want a solution/proof using Combinatorics and contradiction.

Comment: No need to argue by contradiction: By Euler's theorem, $n$ divides $2^{\phi(n)}-1$ and $\phi(n)<n$.

Comment: I know that and that's what I did. But I just wanted a proof using contradiction and combi

Comment: If $2^k-1$ has remainder $n-1$, then $n$ divides $2^k$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

We have to prove that $2^a\cong 1$ holds for at least one $a\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.

Suppose not, then by the pidgeonhole principle (we are assuming $2^a$ never takes on $0$ or $1$ for $a\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$) there is $1\leq b<c\leq n$ so that $2^b\equiv 2^c\bmod n$. We conclude $2^{c-b}\equiv 1 \bmod n$.

Comment: This doesn't work as it is since we need to prove it for $a\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, not $a\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Fixed, thanks a lot. By the way you can also use the fact $\varphi(n)< n$ together with euler's theorem.